# How do I get the 'Next video' from within an array after clicking/watching a video in React

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, lodash

In my React app, from the api I can query a list (array) of videos.

How do get the 'Next video' from within an array after clicking a video?

The flow is as follows:

I get the videos from GraphQL with useQuery hook:

```
const { previousData, data: myVideos = previousData, loading, fetchMore } = useQuery<
    GqlResponse,
    Args
  >(GET_VIDEOS, {
    errorPolicy: 'all',
    notifyOnNetworkStatusChange: true,
  });
```

Then I can return a list of video teasers:

```
        {myVideos.map((video) => (
          <VideoTeaser
            key={video.uuid}
            title={video.title}
            url={video.uuid}
            thumbnail={video.thumbnail}
          />
        ))}
```

With another GraphQl query, I query the video based on `uuid`:

```
const { data } = useQuery<GqlResponse, VideoArgs>(GET_VIDEO, {
    variables: {
      uuid: id,
    },
    errorPolicy: 'all',
  });
```

To the player I pass the `uuid` so it knows which video to play.

`id` (above in the GQL variable) is coming from a query param:
`const id = queryParams.videoId as string;`

After clicking a video teaser from the array list it sends the `uuid` to the query param in the url: `<Link {...linkProps} to={url}>`

Then in another `div` (in an overlay) it plays the clicked video from the list in an overlay in the player:

```
   <Player
      uuid={videoData.uuid}
      thumbnail={videoData.image)
      }
      autoplay
      onEnd={onVideoEnd}
    />
```

So in every overlay the *current* video plays and in a sidebar (next to the *current* video, always the same list of teasers is rendered (always with the same array index and order).

Comment: Create another state with the index of the current video, and when you need to show next/prev increment/decrement the current video's index.

Comment: @OriDrori thanks! Ok so how do I know the index of the current video? When I click on a video teaser from the list it opens a video and plays the 'current' video, in a player next to the list of videos.

Comment: Your question needs some code, and a working example to answer.

Comment: Added some code, it's hard to create a working example. Hope with this you can point me in the correct direction. Thanks a lot

Comment: Where does `myVideos` comes from? How does `Player` knows which video was clicked?

Comment: `myVideos` comes from GraphQL. I pass the video `uuid` to the player. Every video (after clicked) is rendered in an overlay.

Comment: How do you pass the `uuid`?

Comment: With another GraphQl query:
`const { data } = useQuery<GqlResponse, VideoArgs>(GET_VIDEO, {
    variables: {
      uuid: id,
    },
    errorPolicy: 'all',
  });`

Comment: And where does the `id` in `uuid: id,` comes from?

Comment: From a queryParam:  `const id = queryParams.videoId as string;`

Comment: So `VideoTeaser` is a link?

Comment: Yes with a `<Link>`:  like `<Link {...linkProps} to={url}>`

Comment: Now take all the info in the comments, and update your answer with the flow of data in your application. The answer is pretty obvious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you always know the currently played video by it's uuid (`id`), you can use `Array.findIndex()` to find it's current index in the videos array (`myVideos`).

```
const id = queryParams.videoId
const currentIndex = myVideos.findIndex(o => o.uuid === id)
const nextIndex = Math.max(currentIndex + 1, myVideos.length - 1) // the index can't go beyond the last item
const nextId = myVideos.of(nextIndex).uuid
```

And you can use the same idea for previous item.

If you want next to be cyclic - jump to the first item if current is last item, use the remainder operator to find `nextIndex`:

```
const nextIndex = currentIndex + 1 % myVideos.length
```

Comment: Could you maybe have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73661499/how-do-i-refactor-my-code-for-playing-next-video-in-react-app). Thanks